# Array of different $_GET variables

Tags: php, arrays, get

Say you are on this page: `profile.php?user=1&wicked=3`

To get an array like:

```
Array
(
    [user] => 1
    [wicked] => 3
)
```

How do I simply get the first or second value of the array? So if I want the second, I would get: `wicked=3`? Is it something with a foreach loop?

Comment: You should probably explain what you are trying to do because depending on the order of the parameters is probably not the greatest idea.

Comment: foreach will help but as Paolo said you might be doing something wrong

Comment: Unless you're looking for $_GET['wicked'] ?

Comment: I want to determine it by the number of the variable. Like first, second, third, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I get you right, you would like to use number-indexed array.

```
$new_ar = array_values($_GET) ; //["user"=>"1", "wicked"=>"3"] ;
echo $new_ar[1] ; // echoes 2nd value - "3"
```

Comment: Perfect! This is exactly what I was looking for.
`$get_values = array_values($_GET);
$get_keys = array_keys($_GET);

$get = $get_keys[1] . "=" . $get_values[1];
echo $get;`